# Eigenvectors, what do these ones do?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So if I have the system:

$$\underset{\sim}{\dot{y}}=\begin{pmatrix}2 &0\\4&-1\end{pmatrix}\underset{\sim}{y}$$

I get the eigenvalues $\lambda =2,-1$

And then the eigenvectors $\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$

Now I know the eigenvalue $\lambda=2$ will therefore make a line of value $4x=3y$. But what about the eigenvector $(0,1)^T$, what does this do? It seems to do nothing, as shown in the link below.

See [here.](http://onlinesciencetools.com/tools/phaseportrait?dx=2*x&dy=4*x%20-%20y&domx_a=-5&domx_b=5&domy_a=-5&domy_b=5&domt_a=-5&domt_b=5&conc=10) Click anywhere on graph for solution curve.

Comment: Your eigenvalues are a saddle, so stability is?

Comment: @Amzoti Asymptotically unstable saddle. What if I had eigenvalues of $0,2$? What does a zero eigenvalue do to stability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ell = \left\{ t\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} : t \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$

is a straight line running on the $y$-axis.

Comment: Oh, it is generating an infinite slop at $x=0$?

Comment: In a manner of speaking, yes. With initial conditions $(x_0, y_0) = (0,1)$ at time $t = 0$, the solution is $(x,y) = (0,e^{-t})$.

Comment: Thank you(I can't upvote apparently, since I need 15 rep)

Answer (score 0):

In short,

The eigenvector (0,1) is a unit vector in the direction of increasing y, i.e a line x=c.

Your solutions tend asymptotically to the lines x=0 and 4x=3y as can be seen from your phase portrait.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good way to think of it. One unrelated question, what type of stability do I have if my eigenvalues are $0,2$. I would guess this would be a proper node? But I suppose it also has both with same sign, so improper?